# React Routing does not work in an application within a domain with Wordpress

Tags: reactjs, wordpress, .htaccess, react-router, react-router-dom

I have a blog on Wordpress and have independently developed a React app in a subdirectory (**domain.com/app**). The app works, it loads correctly, but when I use any path it gives me two types of errors depending on how I configure htaccess, so I've been able to investigate but I still can't get it to work:

**htaccess version 1:** Error 404 of the theme installed in domain.com appears

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

**htaccess version 2:** 404 server error

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(app|app/.*)$ 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

**In React:**
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";

```
<BrowserRouter basename="/app">
 <Routes>
<Route exact path="/seccion/subseccion/" element={<Component />} />
```

**Current result:**

- Blog: domain.com
- React App: domain.com/app (It works)
- React App with Routing: domain.com/app/section/subsection/ (Does not work)

**On localhost it loads successfully.**

- React App: localhost.3000/app (It works)
- React App with Routing: localhost.3000/app/section/subsection/ (It works)

Can someone guide me what else to do?

Comment: Have you tried configuring .htaccess as per the CRA [docs](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/#serving-apps-with-client-side-routing)? It might be `RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [QSA,L]`.

Comment: Yes, but not work.